# Criar Lista Dinâmica Encadeada

Tags: c, lista, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Estou aprendendo a como trabalhar com listas encadeadas. Em uma das videos aulas que assisti, o professor sugere o seguinte código:

```
struct celula {
      int info;
      struct celula *prox;
};
typedef celula Elem;
typedef celula *Lista;

Lista* iniciaLista(){
       Lista *aux;
       aux=(Lista*) malloc(sizeof(Lista));
       *aux=NULL;
       return aux;
}

int main(){
    Lista *li;
    li=iniciaLista;
```

Pelo que entendi `li` é um ponteiro para "cabeça da lista". A parte que está me quebrando a cabeça é na função de inicialização. Ele cria na memória um espaço de um ponteiro para lista e aloca no `aux`, porém como é possivel fazer `*aux=NULL` se `aux` ainda não aponta para lugar nenhum??
Não sei se deu pra entender minha dúvida, caso alguem queira assitir o video que mencionei acima, segue o link:  [Video Aula Lista Encadeada](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfC61zUVaos&index=11&list=PL8iN9FQ7_jt6H5m4Gm0H89sybzR9yaaka)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Começo por dizer que não sou particularmente fã de duplos `typedefs` para o mesmo tipo sendo que um é ponteiro e outro é a estrutura normal:

```
typedef celula Elem;
typedef celula *Lista;
```

Isto significa que `Elem` e `Lista` correspondem a `celula` e `celula*` respetivamente. No entanto quando eu faço:

```
Lista li;
```

Não é particularmente claro que `li` é um ponteiro a menos que eu vá ver o `typedef`. Isto pode-me induzir em erro no sentido de usar o ponteiro diretamente sem alocar memória.

Posto isto, passemos então à questão:

> como é possivel fazer `*aux=NULL` se `aux` ainda não aponta para lugar
>   nenhum??

Mas `aux` aponta para um lugar, o lugar retornado pelo `malloc`:

```
aux=(Lista*) malloc(sizeof(Lista));
```

Repare que nesta instrução está a guardar o lugar de memória devolvido pelo `malloc`, por isso pode dizer que `aux` já aponta para uma posição de memória. Seria igual se tivesse um `int*` por exemplo:

```
int* x = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)); //guardar o endereço devolvido por malloc
*x = 10; //no lugar apontado por x coloca o valor 10
```

A dificuldade provavelmente provem daqueles 2 `typedefs` que eu mencionei acima, pois na verdade você tem um duplo ponteiro em mão, um `Lista*` que é um `Elem**`. Então para o exemplo que dei acima refletir melhor a sua realidade teria que ser escrito assim:

```
int** x = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*));
*x = NULL;
```

Olhe calmamente para esta instrução. `x` é um ponteiro que aponta para um ponteiro (duplo ponteiro). Está neste caso a dizer que o ponteiro base não aponta para nada:

```
 ----      
| x  | --> NULL
 ----
```

Explicando em português. `x` é um duplo ponteiro de inteiro, e por isso aponta para um `int*` um ponteiro de inteiro. Mas neste momento está a apontar para `NULL` que significa nada.

Num caso que aponta para algo valido, partindo por exemplo deste código:

```
int** x = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*));
int* y = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
*x = y;
*y = 20;
```

Ficaria assim:

```
 ----       ----       ----
| x  | --> | y  | --> | 20 |
 ----       ----       ----
```

Já agora, fazendo uso apenas do primeiro `typedef` podia ter escrito a instrução desta forma:

```
aux = (Elem**) malloc(sizeof(Elem*));
```

Que seria mais perto deste ultimo exemplo que dei.

Como ultimo aparte eu mantive os *casts* para tornar o exemplo parecido com o que tinha, mas eles são desnecessários. Logo podia a instrução original podia ser escrita assim:

```
aux = malloc(sizeof(Lista));
```

Ficando mais simples.

Comment: Muito bom, valeu demaais!!